# How to use Android PdfViewer in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to open pdf in my app after some research i found about "Android PdfViewer" but i don't know how to use it jetpack compose using the interoperability as it is java library.

This is how i using Android PdfViewer but it is not rendering the pdf.

```
@Composable

fun PdfViewer(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
) {
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 24.dp),
    factory = { context ->
        PDFView(context = context, set = null).apply {
            Timber.i(File(dashboardViewModel.pdfUri.value).toUri().toString())
            fromUri(File(dashboardViewModel.pdfUri.value).toUri())
                .load()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis)?

Comment: i tried to use the pdfrenderer library provided by android but i the app crashes every time i tried that, i tried using intent but gives error "exposed beyond app"

Comment: https://github.com/joaopegoraro/ComposePdfViewer

Comment: github.com/joaopegoraro/ComposePdfViewer this library works but its slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working so i made an new activity in which i use xml instead of composables.

To render pdf i am using Android PdfViewer library.

PdfActivity.kt

```
class PdfActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var fileName: String
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf)

    val pdfLayout = findViewById<PDFView>(R.id.pdfViewLayout)
    val intent = intent

    if (intent.extras != null) {
        fileName = intent.extras?.getString("fileName").toString()
    }

    try {
        pdfLayout.fromUri(File("${applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)}/$fileName.pdf").toUri())
            .autoSpacing(true)
            .fitEachPage(true)
            .load()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.d(e.message)
    }
}
}
```

activity_pdf.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PdfActivity">

<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, but it's not perfect.
I loaded the PDF from a local file.
the `fillMaxSize()` appears to be required.

However even though it loads, it doesn't look right. The PDF fills its view space, but spills over and covers the entire screen, and everything in it.

```kotlin
           val file = File(legalDocument.pdfFileName!!)
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                factory = { context ->
                    PDFView(context, null).apply {
                        fromFile(file)
                            .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                            .load()
                    }
                })
```

Comment: checkout my answer, if you put the PDFView into custom xml layout and using view binding inflate that one instead, the visual problems that you've described disappear

Answer (score 0):

My solution to make it work is to create a xml layout for a view, and use view binding to inflate it in the `AndroidView`. That way, the issues described by [@itsymbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2101044/itsymbal) disappear.

*res/layout/pdf_view.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside a Jetpack Compose Composable:

```kotlin
AndroidView(
    factory = {
        PdfViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(it))
            .apply {
                pdfView
                    .fromAsset("asset.pdf")
                    .load()
            }
            .root
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
)
```